# How to pass array with slashes or special characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm using the jquery get() function to send data. The data was array with information that can have special characters like `/` , `?` and `"` . When this happens i can't access to url because the characters spoil the link.

How can i solve that? I did this:

```
function exemple()
    {
      $('.add').click(function(e)
      {
        var kitFamilia = $('#select-family').val();
        var kitReference = $('#referenceinput').val();
        var kitDescription = $('#descriptioninput').val();
        var kitModel = $('#model-input').val();
        var supplier = $('#select-supplier').val();
        var details = [];


          //alert(data);
          details.push({stamp: stamp,family: kitFamilia, reference: kitReference, description: kitDescription, model: kitModel, supplier: supplier});
          details = JSON.stringify(details, null, 2);
          //alert(details);

          $.get("/management-kit/create-kit/"+details, function(data)
          {
            location.reload();
          });

        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should encode the data with [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
$.get("/management-kit/create-kit/"+encodeURIComponent(details), ..
```

Keep in mind that you are sending the JSON encoded as part of the path and not as a parameter. (*and you might also want to remove the 2 space formating of the JSON as it will make the url quite longer*)